# couchbase long running benchmark with python SDK

Tags: python, couchbase

I have issues with couchbase python SDK with long running job.
My job is just a loop with an get access to bucket such as:

```
while True :
  a= cb_bucket.get(key).value
  time.sleep(0.005)
```

This is around 3000 ops /seconds
It works well over 30 mins, and then connection drops 
and has timeout errors.

Is there any known benchmark for long running job and
potential issues with tcp ports opening ?

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/sgload/issues/28

Comment: You may want to show the relevant logs and error messages. Also, can you post the configuration you are using, as well as the version of Couchbase Server, how many nodes you are using, etc.

Comment: Also, if you are just trying to do some stress testing or performance testing, you might want to try cbc-pillowfight, which is a command line utility that's designed for that: http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-c-client-2.4.0/md_cbc-pillowfight.html

Comment: Am not stress-testing, just would like to see benchmark results on couchbase in that scenario.